# What is the best alternative of innerHTML to improve performance

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, innerhtml

I'm working on a project and for that project I have created a custom dropdown international country code selection section, and for that I have injected all the SVG flag icons using innerHTML and I have noticed that after using the 240 lines of innerHTML the performance/ loading speed of my website is being negatively affected by the innerHTML.

Because, the Option tag doesn't support any other HTML tag that why I have to manually inject the span tag to every custom div using innerHTML which makes my site slower. is there any alternate way available to do the same thing using JS. or can we use the innerHTML to inject span tag's for all 240 countries at once by using loops or something.

I need JS solution only. CSS is not working for mine problems.

```js
  // Autoclick on the parent div to hide the Dropdown after loading a page (Bug)
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      document.querySelector(".country-code-selector").click();
  });

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

      const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      const link = document.createElement('link');
      link.rel = 'stylesheet';
      link.type = 'text/css';
      link.href = 'https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css';
      head.appendChild(link);

      // Get dropdowns and form
      const dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('[cc-data-dropdown]');
      const form = document.querySelector('.country-code-selector form');

      // Check if dropdowns exist on page
      if (dropdowns.length > 0) {
          // Loop through dropdowns and create custom dropdown for each select element
          dropdowns.forEach(dropdown => {
              createCustomDropdown(dropdown);
          });
      }

      // Check if form element exist on page
      if (form !== null) {
          // When form is submitted console log the value of the select field
          form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('Selected country:', form.querySelector('[name="country"]').value);
          });
      }

      // Create custom dropdown
      function createCustomDropdown(dropdown) {
          // Get all options and convert them from nodelist to array
          const options = dropdown.querySelectorAll('option');
          const optionsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(options);

          optionsArr[0].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-afg"></span> Afganistan (+69)';
          optionsArr[1].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-alb"></span> Albania (+355)';
          optionsArr[2].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dza"></span> Algeria (+213)';
          optionsArr[3].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-asm"></span> American Samoa (+1-684)';
          optionsArr[4].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-and"></span> Andorra (+376)';
          optionsArr[5].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ago"></span> Angola (+244)';
          optionsArr[6].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aia"></span> Anguilla (+1-264)';
          optionsArr[7].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ata"></span> Antarctica (+672)';
          optionsArr[8].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-atg"></span> Antigua and Barbuda (+1-268)';
          optionsArr[9].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arg"></span> Argentina (+54)';
          optionsArr[10].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-arm"></span> Armenia (+374)';
          optionsArr[11].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-abw"></span> Aruba (+297)';
          optionsArr[12].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aus"></span> Australia (+61)';
          optionsArr[13].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aut"></span> Austria (+43)';
          optionsArr[14].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-aze"></span> Azerbaijan (+994)';
          optionsArr[15].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhs"></span> Bahamas (+1-242)';
          optionsArr[16].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bhr"></span> Bahrain (+973)';
          optionsArr[17].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgd"></span> Bangladesh (+880)';
          optionsArr[18].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brb"></span> Barbados (+1-246)';
          optionsArr[19].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blr"></span> Belarus (+375)';
          optionsArr[20].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bel"></span> Belgium (+32)';
          optionsArr[21].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-blz"></span> Belize (+501)';
          optionsArr[22].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ben"></span> Benin (+229)';
          optionsArr[23].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bmu"></span> Bermuda (+1-441)';
          optionsArr[24].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-btn"></span> Bhutan (+975)';
          optionsArr[25].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bol"></span> Bolivia (+591)';
          optionsArr[26].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bih"></span> Bosnia and Herzegovina (+387)';
          optionsArr[27].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bwa"></span> Botswana (+267)';
          optionsArr[28].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bra"></span> Brazil (+55)';
          optionsArr[29].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-iot"></span> British Indian Ocean Territory (+246)';
          optionsArr[30].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-vgb"></span> British Virgin Islands (+1-284)';
          optionsArr[31].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-brn"></span> Brunei (+673)';
          optionsArr[32].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bgr"></span> Bulgaria (+359)';
          optionsArr[33].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bfa"></span> Burkina Faso (+226)';
          optionsArr[34].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-bdi"></span> Burundi (+257)';
          optionsArr[35].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-khm"></span> Cambodia (+855)';
          optionsArr[36].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cmr"></span> Cameroon (+237)';
          optionsArr[37].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-can"></span> Canada (+1)';
          optionsArr[38].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cpv"></span> Cape Verde (+238)';
          optionsArr[39].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cym"></span> Cayman Islands (+1-345)';
          optionsArr[40].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-caf"></span> Central African Republic (+236)';
          optionsArr[41].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tcd"></span> Chad (+235)';
          optionsArr[42].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chl"></span> Chile (+56)';
          optionsArr[43].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-chn"></span> China (+86)';
          optionsArr[44].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cxr"></span> Christmas Island (+61)';
          optionsArr[45].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cck"></span> Cocos Islands (+61)';
          optionsArr[46].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-col"></span> Colombia (+57)';
          optionsArr[47].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-com"></span> Comoros (+269)';
          optionsArr[48].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cok"></span> Cook Islands (+682)';
          optionsArr[49].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cri"></span> Costa Rica (+506)';
          optionsArr[50].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-hrv"></span> Croatia (+385)';
          optionsArr[51].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cub"></span> Cuba (+53)';
          optionsArr[52].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cuw"></span> Curacao (+599)';
          optionsArr[53].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cyp"></span> Cyprus (+357)';
          optionsArr[54].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cze"></span> Czech Republic (+420)';
          optionsArr[55].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-cod"></span> Democratic Republic of the Congo (+243)';
          optionsArr[56].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dnk"></span> Denmark (+45)';
          optionsArr[57].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dji"></span> Djibouti (+253)';
          optionsArr[58].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dma"></span> Dominica (+1-767)';
          optionsArr[59].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-dom"></span> Dominican Republic (+1-809)';
          optionsArr[60].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-tls"></span> East Timor (+670)';
          optionsArr[61].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-ecu"></span> Ecuador (+593)';
          optionsArr[62].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-egy"></span> Egypt (+20)';
          optionsArr[63].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-slv"></span> El Salvador (+503)';
          optionsArr[64].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-gnq"></span> Equatorial Guinea (+240)';
          optionsArr[65].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eri"></span> Eritrea (+291)';
          optionsArr[66].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-est"></span> Estonia (+372)';
          optionsArr[67].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-eth"></span> Ethiopia (+251)';
          optionsArr[68].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-flk"></span> Falkland Islands (+500)';
          optionsArr[69].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fro"></span> Faroe Islands (+298)';
          optionsArr[70].innerHTML = '<span class="flag-icon flag-icon-fji"></span> Fiji (+679)';
          // More 169 Countries (Currently not added here) -
          optionsArr[71].innerHTML = 'No Data Found';


          // Create custom dropdown element and add class dropdown to it
          // Insert it in the DOM after the select field
          const customDropdown = document.createElement('div');
          customDropdown.classList.add('cc-dropdown');
          dropdown.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', customDropdown);

          // Create element for selected option
          // Add class to this element, text from the first option in select field and append it to custom dropdown
          const selected = document.createElement('div');
          selected.classList.add('cc-dropdown-selected');
          selected.innerHTML = 'Tel-Code';
          customDropdown.appendChild(selected);

          // Create element for dropdown menu, add class to it and append it to custom dropdown
          // Add click event to selected element to toggle dropdown menu
          const menu = document.createElement('div');
          menu.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu');
          customDropdown.appendChild(menu);
          selected.addEventListener('click', toggleDropdown.bind(menu));

          // Create serach input element
          // Add class, type and placeholder to this element and append it to menu element
          const search = document.createElement('input');
          search.placeholder = 'Search Your Country...';
          search.type = 'text';
          search.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-search');
          menu.appendChild(search);

          // Create wrapper element for menu items, add class to it and append to menu element
          const menuItemsWrapper = document.createElement('div');
          menuItemsWrapper.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-items');
          menu.appendChild(menuItemsWrapper);

          // Loop through all options and create custom option for each option and append it to items wrapper element
          // Add click event for each custom option to set clicked option as selected option
          optionsArr.forEach(option => {
              const item = document.createElement('div');
              item.classList.add('cc-dropdown-menu-item');
              item.dataset.value = option.value;
              item.innerHTML = option.innerHTML;
              menuItemsWrapper.appendChild(item);

              item.addEventListener('click', setSelected.bind(item, selected, dropdown, menu));
          });

          // Add selected class to first custom option
          // menuItemsWrapper.querySelector('div').classList.add('selected');

          // Add input event to search input element to filter items
          // Add click event to document element to close custom dropdown if clicked outside of it
          // Hide original dropdown(select)
          search.addEventListener('input', filterItems.bind(search, optionsArr, menu));
          document.addEventListener('click', closeIfClickedOutside.bind(customDropdown, menu));
          dropdown.style.display = 'none';

      }


      // Toggle dropdown
      function toggleDropdown() {
          // Check if dropdown is opened and if it is close it, otherwise open it and focus search input

          if (this.offsetParent !== null) {
              this.style.display = 'none';
          } else {
              this.style.display = 'block';
              this.querySelector('input').focus();
          }
      }

      // Set selected option
      function setSelected(selected, dropdown, menu) {
          // Get value and label from clicked custom option
          const value = this.dataset.value;
          const label = this.innerHTML;

          // Change the text on selected element
          // Change the value on select field  

          filterDate = /(<span\b[^<>]*><\/span>\s*)\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\s*\((\+[\d-]+)\)/g;
          selected.innerHTML = label.replace(filterDate, `$1$2`);
          dropdown.value = value;

          // Close the menu
          // Reset search input value
          // Remove selected class from previously selected option and show all divs if they were filtered
          // Add selected class to clicked option
          menu.style.display = 'none';
          menu.querySelector('input').value = '';
          menu.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
              if (div.classList.contains('selected')) {
                  div.classList.remove('selected');
              }
              if (div.offsetParent === null) {
                  div.style.display = 'block';
              }
          });
          this.classList.add('selected');
      }

      // Filter items
      function filterItems(itemsArr, menu) {
          // Get all custom options
          // Get the value of search input and convert it to all lowercase characters
          // Get filtered items
          // Get the indexes of filtered items
          const customOptions = menu.querySelectorAll('.cc-dropdown-menu-items div');
          const value = this.value.toLowerCase();
          const filteredItems = itemsArr.filter(item => item.value.toLowerCase().includes(value));
          const indexesArr = filteredItems.map(item => itemsArr.indexOf(item));

          // Check if option is not inside indexes array and hide it and if it is inside indexes array and it is hidden show it


          var options = itemsArr.length;
          itemsArr.forEach(option => {
              if (!indexesArr.includes(itemsArr.indexOf(option))) {
                  customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'none';
                  options -= 1;
                  if (options <= 0) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.length - 1].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              } else {
                  if (customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].offsetParent === null) {
                      customOptions[itemsArr.indexOf(option)].style.display = 'block';
                  }
              }
          });
      }

      // Close dropdown if clicked outside dropdown element
      function closeIfClickedOutside(menu, e) {
          if (e.target.closest('.cc-dropdown') === null && e.target !== this && menu.offsetParent !== null) {
              menu.style.display = 'none';
          }
      }


  });
```

```css
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 2px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar {
     background-color: #323757;
     width: 14px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
     background-color: #e8576f;
     border: 4px solid #323757;
     z-index: -1;
     width: 2px;
     min-height: 50px;
}
 #phone-number {
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .tx {
     margin-left: 120px;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox {
     display: flex;
}
 .frm div:nth-child(3) .inputBox .ln {
     margin-left: 120px;
     width: calc(100% - 120px);
}
 .cc-dropdown {
     position: relative;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 116px;
     height: 40px;
     padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     transition: box-shadow .3s ease;
     background-color: #323757;
     border-radius: 3px;
     font-size: 15px;
     color: #fff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected::after {
     top: calc(50% - 2px);
     right: 10px;
     border: solid transparent;
     content: '';
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     position: absolute;
     border-top-color:#000;
     border-width: 4px;
     margin-left: -4px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected:hover {
     box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     left: 0;
     width: 273px;
     border: 3px solid #323757;
     margin-right: -2px;
     border-top: 0;
     background-color: #fff;
     z-index: +9;
     margin-top: 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items {
     max-height: 200px;
     width: 270px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: hidden;
     z-index: +9;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search {
     display: block;
     width: 270px;
     border: 0;
     border-right: 3px solid #323757;
     padding: 14px 0px 14px 10px;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: 550;
     color: #fff;
     outline: 0;
     background-color: #323757;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-search::placeholder {
     color: rgb(214, 214, 214)!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item {
     width: 267px;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #323757a6;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-weight: 550;
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: +9;
     user-select: none;
     padding: 10px 18px 10px 10px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-items .flag-icon {
     height: 15px;
     width: 26px;
     margin-right: 3px;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:hover {
     background-color: rgb(228, 228, 228);
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected {
     border: none;
}
 .cc-dropdown-selected .flag-icon {
     margin-right: 5px!important;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected, .cc-dropdown-menu-item.selected:hover {
     background-color: #323757c2;
     color: #ffffff;
}
 .cc-dropdown-menu-item:last-child {
     pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="country-code-selector">
   <form class="cc-form">
      <div class="cc-form-group">
         <select id="country" name="country" cc-data-dropdown>
            <option value="Afganistan"></option>
            <option value="Albania"></option>
            <option value="Algeria"></option>
            <option value="American Samoa"></option>
            <option value="Andorra"></option>
            <option value="Angola"></option>
            <option value="Anguilla"></option>
            <option value="Antarctica"></option>
            <option value="Antigua and Barbuda"></option>
            <option value="Argentina"></option>
            <option value="Armenia"></option>
            <option value="Aruba"></option>
            <option value="Australia"></option>
            <option value="Austria"></option>
            <option value="Azerbaijan"></option>
            <option value="Bahamas"></option>
            <option value="Bahrain"></option>
            <option value="Bangladesh"></option>
            <option value="Barbados"></option>
            <option value="Belarus"></option>
            <option value="Belgium"></option>
            <option value="Belize"></option>
            <option value="Benin"></option>
            <option value="Bermuda"></option>
            <option value="Bhutan"></option>
            <option value="Bolivia"></option>
            <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina"></option>
            <option value="Botswana"></option>
            <option value="Brazil"></option>
            <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory"></option>
            <option value="British Virgin Islands"></option>
            <option value="Brunei"></option>
            <option value="Bulgaria"></option>
            <option value="Burkina Faso"></option>
            <option value="Burundi"></option>
            <option value="Cambodia"></option>
            <option value="Cameroon"></option>
            <option value="Canada"></option>
            <option value="Cape Verde"></option>
            <option value="Cayman Islands"></option>
            <option value="Central African Republic"></option>
            <option value="Chad"></option>
            <option value="Chile"></option>
            <option value="China"></option>
            <option value="Christmas Island"></option>
            <option value="Cocos Islands"></option>
            <option value="Colombia"></option>
            <option value="Comoros"></option>
            <option value="Cook Islands"></option>
            <option value="Costa Rica"></option>
            <option value="Croatia"></option>
            <option value="Cuba"></option>
            <option value="Curacao"></option>
            <option value="Cyprus"></option>
            <option value="Czech Republic"></option>
            <option value="Democratic Republic of the Congo"></option>
            <option value="Denmark"></option>
            <option value="Djibouti"></option>
            <option value="Dominica"></option>
            <option value="Dominican Republic"></option>
            <option value="East Timor"></option>
            <option value="Ecuador"></option>
            <option value="Egypt"></option>
            <option value="El Salvador"></option>
            <option value="Equatorial Guinea"></option>
            <option value="Eritrea"></option>
            <option value="Estonia"></option>
            <option value="Ethiopia"></option>
            <option value="Falkland Islands"></option>
            <option value="Faroe Islands"></option>
            <option value="Fiji"></option>
            <option></option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is that it isn't the `innerHTML` necessarily causing the performance hit but the 240 SVG images that need to be loaded for your flags. Re loops: you could merge all the relevant information into an array of objects (`{ name, code, icon }`, for example), and then loop over that to create the HTML

Comment: Also, instead of updating each DOM element directly in the loop, it‘s far more performant to create a documentfragment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment). Since this is not part of the DOM but only in memory, it can be changed quickly and performant in the loop. The documentfragment could be the drop-down where you add the options. When the loop is done, add the whole thing at once to the DOM (so just one DOM update instead of 200).

Comment: Of course the other thing to avoid would be to not have invalid HTML which is what you're doing by adding markup to a select option. Instead have a div with a scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not solve the performance issue (although it may go some way to alleviate it a little) but it will help reduce the complexity of the code/markup.

At the moment you have HTML markup that builds the `select`, with almost duplicate JS code that describes what should be added to each option in that select.

If you merge all of the country information into one dataset you can remove the options from the `select` and programmatically generate them.

Further: if you get rid of the `select` altogether and replace it with a list you can resolve the problem of having invalid HTML (`option` doesn't accept anything other than text, but a list `li` item has no problem with additional markup).

This example uses a very reduced dataset, and builds the country list using that data. When a change is made in the `input` the dataset is filtered, and the list markup updated.

```js
// Cache the elements
const button = document.querySelector('.telcode');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const list = document.querySelector('.list');

// Add event listeners to the button, input, and list
// We use a process called "event delegation" on the list
// to catch events from its children as they "bubble up" the DOM
// https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/
button.addEventListener('click', handleButton);
input.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
list.addEventListener('click', handleListClick);
document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);

// Handles the document click - it checks to see if the clicked
// part of the document has a parent element which is either
// `null` or is the HTML element, and then closes the container
// if it's open
function handleDocumentClick(e) {
  const { parentElement } = e.target;
  if (!parentElement || parentElement.nodeName === 'HTML') {
    if (container.classList.contains('show')) {
      container.classList.remove('show');
    }  
  }
}

// All of the data held as objects within an array
const data = [
  { name: 'Afganistan', code: '69', flag: 'afg' },
  { name: 'Barbados', code: '1-246', flag: 'brb' },
  { name: 'Bolivia', code: '591', flag: 'bol' },
  { name: 'Cuba', code: '53', flag: 'cub' },
  { name: 'Fiji', code: '679', flag: 'fji' },
];

// Filters the data based on the characters
// at the start of the provided name
function filterData(data, value) {
  return data.filter(obj => {
    return (
      obj.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
      || obj.code.toLowerCase().startsWith(value.toLowerCase())
    );
  });
}

// Create a series of list items based on the
// data passed to it
function createListHtml(data) {
  return data.map(obj => {
    const { name, code, flag } = obj;
    return `
      <li
        class="item"
        data-name="${name}"
        data-code="${code}"
        data-flag="${flag}"
      >
        <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
        <div class="name">${name} (+${code})</div>
      </li>
    `;
  }).join('');
}

// Toggle the container on/off
function handleButton() {
  container.classList.toggle('show');
}

// No data available list item
function createNoDataHtml() {
  return '<li class="nodata">No data available</li>';
}

// When the input is changed filter the data
// according to the current value, and then
// create some list items using that filtered data
function handleInput(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;
  if (value) {
    const filtered = filterData(data, value);
    if (filtered.length) {
      list.innerHTML = createListHtml(filtered);
    } else {
      list.innerHTML = createNoDataHtml();
    }
  } else {
    list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
  }
}

// Create some button HTML
function createButtonHtml(code, flag) {
  return `
    <div class="flag-icon flag-icon-${flag}"></div>
    <div class="code">+${code}</div>
  `;
}

// Updates the selected list by removing the `selected`
// class from all items, and then adding one to the clicked
// item
function updateSelected(list, item) {
  const items = list.querySelectorAll('.item');
  items.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('selected'));
  item.classList.add('selected');
}

// When an item is clicked, grab the relevant data
// attributes, create the new button HTML, and then 
// close the container
function handleListClick(e) {
  const item = e.target.closest('li') || e.target;
  if (item.classList.contains('item')) {
    const { code, flag } = item.dataset;
    button.innerHTML = createButtonHtml(code, flag);
    updateSelected(list, item);
    container.classList.remove('show');
  }
}

list.innerHTML = createListHtml(data);
```

```css
.telcode { margin-bottom: 1em; display: flex;}
.telcode div.code, .item div.name { margin-left: 0.25em; }
.container { display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
.list { height: 100px; list-style: none; margin: 1em 0 0 0; padding: 0; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px soldi darkgray; }
.item { display: flex; padding: 0.25em; border: 1px solid lightgray; }
.item:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.item:hover, .item.selected { background-color: lightyellow; }
```

```html
<link href="https://amitdutta.co.in/flag/css/flag-icon.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="telcode">Tel code</button>
<section class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search for country" />
  <ul class="list"></ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Sir for the one of the finest code and explanation, but Sir I'm trying to add few more functions in your code but I can't able to understand how and where to do. Like -   (1). I want to filter data using country code also, means when any user only type the country code in search box I want to show that specific country.   (2). I want to close the dropdown when user clicks outside the container.   (3). I want to show a message "No Country Found" after the search box if the user entered data doesn't matches with my string or country code. In this regard can you help me a little.

Comment: Sir is it not possible to search with both "country name" and "country code"? because after your edit the search box is working with country code only not with the name. Also the "No data available" is selectable and returning "+undefined"

Comment: I have used the pointer-events: none; for "No data available" li, but still it is selecting the option. Sir how can I make this text non-selectable.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your valuable time and effort.

Comment: Sir If any user selects any option, and after that if the user reopen the dropdown menu how can I highligh the selected option using background color as a selected option in dropdown.

Comment: I added an extra function (`updateSelected`) to add a `selected` class to the clicked item, and removing the class from all the other items. @GupaDutta